# Can't implement KeystoneJS Pagination concurrently

Tags: javascript, pagination, keystonejs, locals

I'm trying to implement pagination in keystone js andf I'm doing it as follows:

### Model

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Test = new keystone.List('Test', {
    map: {name: 'title'},
    label: 'Test',
    singular: 'Test',
    plural: 'Tests',
    autokey: {path: 'slug', from: 'title', unique: true} 
});

Test.add({
    description: {type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true, height: 300 }
});

Test.register();
```

### Route / View

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Test = keystone.list('Test');
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;

    // Set locals
    locals.section = 'test';
    locals.data = {
        test: []
    };


    Test.paginate({
        page: req.query.page || 1,
        perPage: 2,
        maxPages: 5
    })
    .exec(function(err, results) {
        locals.data.test = results;
        next(err);
    });

    // Load All Terms
    view.query('test', keystone.list('Test').model.find()); 

    // Render view
    view.render('test');
}
```

### In Index.js

```
app.all('/test', routes.views.test);
```

### In middleware.js

```
res.locals.navLinksFooter = [
    { label: 'Test', key: 'test', href: '/test' },
    .....
];
```

### Template

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <span class="pull-right">
            {{>pagination}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row row-content panel--outer panel--outer--trans">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="panel--news-detail">
        {{# each test}}
            <p>{{{description}}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to go to the page I get the following error:

"ReferenceError: next is not defined"

Some pointers and possible causes. I've already set up pagination for blog posts on a separate page using:

```
locals.data = {
    test: []
};
```

If I comment out "next(err)", the pagination buttons appear but clickiong on the arrow takes me to the second page of blog/news items.

Things are obviously getting mixed up somewhere here. I suspect it's due to my mishandling of locals but I can't seem to find any in depth explanation on the keystone site of how locals are supposed to work.

I ultimately want to apply different filters to the mongo collection and have it running in a series of bootstrap tabs but I think I need to get the basics sorted out first.

Has anyone been faced with a similar situation and been able to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` is a callback function that runs within your Express route. You don't have it defined as an argument in your route at all; part of the problem is also that you are trying to load the data synchronously, which doesn't work here.

Use the `view.init` function to expose the `next` function, then call it when you've loaded information from your database into `locals.data`.

**route/view**

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Test = keystone.list('Test');
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {

    var view = new keystone.View(req, res);
    var locals = res.locals;

    // Set locals
    locals.section = 'test';
    locals.data = {
        test: []
    };


    view.on('init', function (next) {
        Test.paginate({
            page: req.query.page || 1,
            perPage: 2,
            maxPages: 5
        })
        .exec(function(err, results) {
            locals.data.test = results;
            next(err);
        });
    });

    // Load All Terms
    view.query('test', keystone.list('Test').model.find()); 

    // Render view
    view.render('test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - has done the trick - quite a shocking miss on my part there! 8-( The ongoing issue of it then redirecting to the blog when you click on pagination I've traced to templates/views/helpers/index.js - seems as though I'm going to have to write some specific helpers for each instance of pagination and then match them to a specific pagination partial. I'm hoping this won't be too much of a problem but as it's midnight here and I've been working since 3pm this afternoon, it's one that's going to have to wait till tomorrow.